# I am facing Multidex issue while running the app in Android studio 3.0 Beta 5

Tags: android, android-multidex

I have followed the various links for this solution but nothing worked.
Below is the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

I have also enabled multidex and have added google services plugin at bottom of build.gradle file.Here is the build.gradle compiler dependencies:

```
compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.1'
compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.+'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.+'
compile('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1') {
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
}
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'
compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.1.2'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-httpclient:3.1.2'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.1.2'
compile files('libs/beacon_sdk.jar')
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
    exclude module: "httpclient"
}

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'
compile 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this just 
**split google play services it will worked**

**use this**

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.4.0'
```

**insted of this**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
```

Comment: @Aditi Note: If your project is configured for multidex with minSdkVersion 20 or lower, and you deploy to target devices running Android 4.4 (API level 20) or lower, Android Studio disables Instant Run.

Comment: I am running the app on device with android 25 and minsdk for app is 19

Comment: @Aditi  disables Instant Run. than try

Comment: After disabling instant run i am now getting error: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/DefaultRetryPolicy;

Comment: **clean-rebuild-run** @Aditi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155323/discussion-between-aditi-and-nilesh-rathod).

Answer (score 2):

Versions of the platform prior to Android 5.0 (API level 21) use the Dalvik runtime for executing app code. By default, Dalvik limits apps to a single classes.dex bytecode file per APK. In order to get around this limitation, you can add the multidex support library to your project:

Add following dependency

```
  android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

if you do override the Application class but it's not possible to change the base class, then you can instead override the attachBaseContext() method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex:

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```